# JQuery plugin called mbComingsoon not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Okay I'm trying to use this plugin and I must add I'm a noob :D So I couldn't figure it out how to remove days from counter and how to activated the call back to do alert function, for example I tried this

$('#myCounter').mbComingsoon(new Date(2018, 6, 16, 19, 8));

```
$('#myCounter').mbComingsoon({
    expiryDate: Date,
    interval: Number,
    localization: {
        days: "",
        hours: "",
        minutes: "",
        seconds: "",
    },

    speed: Number,
    callBack:function() {
        alert('end');
    },
});

$('#myCounter').mbComingSoon('start');
```

but after countdown gets ended I do not receive any alert. please help me in these 2 matters, thanks for your time guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as I've seen there is no official way to hide the days but you can do it like this:

```
$('#myCounter').mbComingsoon({
    expiryDate: new Date(2018, 06, 16, 18, 50, 00, 00),
    localization: {
        days: "", //leave empty
        hours: "hours",
        minutes: "minutes",
        seconds: "seconds",
    },
    callBack:function() {
        alert('end');
    },
});

// hide the days counter        
$(".days").hide();
```

your callback function actualy works in my case? do you get any error?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback dude :) I had a line of code abode my this code which was causing the alert not to work which was this one >>>$('#myCounter').mbComingsoon(new Date(2018, 6, 16, 23, 1));